# Comparing Ranges and Copying

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have been creating a small project that will allow a user to import and export data from work worksheet to another. I will attach screenshots to try and explain what i am trying to achieve.
I have the import section of my program working without fault and i can import all jobs that are of colour "Red" from my second worksheet. However once the row has been changed to colour "Green" in worksheet 1 it will then be exported back to sheet 2 and in turn will change the once "Red" job to "Green" effecting no other rows in sheet 2.

I have tried to implement the code as best as i could however i keep getting errors when comparing the my unique cell in both ranges.

As of just now when i run the code it will copy over the value 10 times and paste over all data from row "A4" to row "A14"

Worksheet One
[image]

Worksheet Two
[image]

```
Sub Button3_Click()

'@Author - Jason Hughes(AlmightyThud)
'@Version - 1.0
'@Date - 0/03/2015
'@Description - To Export all Completed Jobs to the "Daily Work Orders" Spreadsheet
'Once exported it will scan for the unique job number in the list and override the existing values

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Declare initial variables for this button'
Dim copyComplete As Boolean
copyComplete = False
Dim lR As Long
'----------------------------------'
'#When this code is uncommented it will delete all values in column A#'

Dim jobID As Range
Dim jobID2 As Range
Set jobID = Sheets("Daily Screen Update").Range("A4:A31")
Set jobID2 = Sheets("Daily Work Orders").Range("A4:A10000")


'----------------------------------'

'Activate the sheet you will be looping through'
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Screen Update").Activate

'Simple loop that will loop through all cells to check if the cell is green'
'If the cell is green then the loop will copy the cell, once copied the loop will check'
'the "Daily Work Orders" Sheet for a job ID with a similar ID and paste over it'
For Each greenjob In Range("A4:A31")
    If greenjob.Cells.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) Then
        greenjob.Cells.EntireRow.Copy
        For j = 4 To 31
            For i = 4 To 10
                If jobID.Cells(j, 1).Value = jobID2.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
                    Sheets("Daily Work Orders").Range("A" & j).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                    copyComplete = True
                End If
            Next i
        Next j
    End If
Next

'Make a check to ensure that the data has been copied
If copyComplete = True Then
    MsgBox ("All completed jobs have been have been added to Daily Work Orders")
ElseIf copyComplete = False Then
    MsgBox ("Nothing has been added to Daily Work Orders")
End If


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three `For` loops:

1. `For Each greenjob In Range("A4:A31")`
2. `For j = 4 To 31`
3. `For i = 4 To 10`

Loop 1 goes through all of the rows on Worksheet One and identifies ones that need to be copied, so Loop 2 going through all of those rows again each time Loop 1 catches one doesn't make sense.

Instead, just use the Job Number from the row identified in Loop 1 and compare it to the Job Numbers on Worksheet 1 using Loop 3.

So, remove `For j = 4 To 31` and `Next j`, and replace

```
If jobID.Cells(j, 1).Value = jobID2.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
```

with

```
If greenjob.Value = jobID2.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
```

since `greenjob` is, conveniently, the cell in column A that contains the job number.